# Unable to run a Flink Job on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink Job on Kubernetes and trying to read JSON messages from a Kafka topic as shown below:
var consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer("inv-json", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
And I get the following error and the job fails,
**ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler   [] - Exception occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application.**

I am not sure how to resolve this (the same code runs file locally) - I googled this error, but did not find any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: It would help to see more about how the k8s cluster is configured and deployed, how the job is being submitted, etc. But the problem is that the application JAR file isn't showing up.

Comment: Thank you David for your response. I had figured out what the issue was - it was the way I was packaging the application jar.

Answer (score 0):

This is in reference to Flink v1.12.1-scala.2.12-java11 application deployed on Kubernetes using Lyft's K8S operator. The application that I was trying to run reads streaming data from Kafka and does processing. But the job never got submitted/ran and failed with the above error which is not quite helpful in identifying and fixing the issue. I just had to try out several options including creating a fat jar with all the dependencies included in the jar and run it on Kubernetes and that resolved the issue. I later improvized by switching to a shaded jar.